# Cannot assign value to stored property from within computed property

Tags: swift

I created a struct in which I have a property '_photo' that is lazily assigned when the computed property 'photo' is called.  I keep getting the error

> Cannot assign to '_photo' in 'self'

Here is the code. I wrote the computed method in both Swift 1.1 (photo1) and swift 1.2 (photo2) syntax. Both give the same compile time error as noted above.

What changes are needed to fix that error?

```
import UIKit

public struct PhotoStruct {
    var _photo:UIImage?
    var urlString:String?

    init(image:UIImage?, url:String?){
        self._photo = image
        self.urlString = url

    }

    init(url:String?){
        self.urlString = url
    }


    var photo1:UIImage? {

        if let theURL = self._photo {
            return self._photo
        }else{
            if let urlString = self.urlString{
                if let url = NSURL(string: urlString as String){
                    if let imageData :NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url){
                        if let image:UIImage = UIImage(data:imageData){

                            self._photo = image //** Cannot assign error is here**
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return self._photo
        }
    }

    var photo2:UIImage? {

        if let theURL = self._photo {
            return self._photo
        }else{
            if let  urlString = self.urlString,
                    url = NSURL(string: urlString as String),
                    imageData :NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url),
                    image:UIImage = UIImage(data:imageData){

                            self._photo = image //** Cannot assign error is here**
            }
            return self._photo
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 16):

As for `struct`, If you want to mutate the `self` property inside computed properties, you have to explicitly declare the getter as `mutating get { .. }`

```
public struct PhotoStruct {
    var _photo:UIImage?
    var urlString:String?

    init(image:UIImage?, url:String?){
        self._photo = image
        self.urlString = url
    }

    init(url:String?){
        self.urlString = url
    }

    var photo1:UIImage? {
        mutating get {
    //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
            // you can set `self._photo = image` here
        }
    }

    var photo2:UIImage? {
        mutating get {
    //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
            // you can set `self._photo = image` here
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, the struct itself have to be mutable:

```
var pVar:PhotoStruct = PhotoStruct(image: nil, url: nil)
pVar.photo1 // no problem
let pLet:PhotoStruct = PhotoStruct(image: nil, url: nil)
pLet.photo1 // < [!] error: immutable value of type 'PhotoStruct' only has mutating members named 'photo1'
```

**One caveat**:

As far as I know, `mutating get { }` feature is undocumented on [the language reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AboutTheLanguageReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH29-ID345).

Comment: Interesting, didn't know "mutating get".

Answer (score 11):

`Structs` are value types and they are immutable.
This means that you cannot set variable and mutate self.
If you need to mutate struct, you have to make `mutating func`

```
public struct PhotoStruct {
    var _photo:UIImage?
    var urlString:String?

   mutating func loadPhoto() -> UIImage {
    .. Code here
   _photo = UIImage(data:imageData)
   // Here you mutate a struct, but it's ok because we make method as mutating
  }
}
```

In you example I would make a mutating method instead of property

```
mutating func photo () -> UIImage? {

    if let photo = self._photo {
        return photo
    } else {
        if let urlString = self.urlString,
        url = NSURL(string: urlString),
        imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url),
        image = UIImage(data:imageData) {
            self._photo = image
        }
        return self._photo
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, everyone!!  So great to have this community!

Comment: Here is a link to an article that explains this further for those who are having trouble understanding the answers people have given.  http://natashatherobot.com/mutating-functions-swift-structs/

Answer (score 5):

`PhotoStruct` is a `struct` and therefore a *value type*. For value types,
only methods explicitly marked as `mutating` can modify the properties
of `self`, so this is not possible within a computed property.

If you change  `PhotoStruct` to be a `class` then your code compiles
without problems.

Comment: Swift has these silly nuances where many constructs are _similar_ to each other but still _different_.

Comment: what's weird is you can't set a property on a struct from within another property's computed `get` but you _can_ set the desired property from another properity's `didSet` ! I can't for the life of me figure out why the behavior would be different between these two.